# How to convert character and dates to dates?

Tags: r, lubridate

My data comes from excel. The dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format:

```
certificado$fecha <- c("22/02/2019", "43679", "22/02/2019", "22/01/2019", "28/10/2019", 
"18/09/2019")
```

However, R is reading some dates as mm/dd/yyyy. My code is supposed to convert all of them to an specific format.

```
certificados$Fecha <- as.Date(certificados$Fecha,format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

But im getting NAs due to date format issues.

Comment: The dates are in different format as you showed: `"22/02/2019", "43679"`. So you cannot just use `"%d/%m/%Y"` to parse that column, you may need to clean your data first.

Comment: It seems likely that you are getting data that has been (at some point) in Excel. If it is originally created/sourced in Excel, I suggest one approach would be to standardize the data *there* first, and then work on the import process into R. There are certainly tricks you can do to try to parse all of these (I'll look for a previous answer of mine shortly), but fixing the source is a much-preferred approach, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot fix this at the source, this code finds both formats:

```r
vec <- c("22/02/2019", "43679", "22/02/2019", "22/01/2019", "28/10/2019", "18/09/2019")
out <- as.Date(vec, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
out
# [1] "2019-02-22" NA           "2019-02-22" "2019-01-22" "2019-10-28" "2019-09-18"

isna <- is.na(out)
out[isna] <- as.Date(as.integer(vec[isna]), origin = "1900-01-01")
out
# [1] "2019-02-22" "2019-08-04" "2019-02-22" "2019-01-22" "2019-10-28" "2019-09-18"
```