# Format Multiple Date in 1 Column in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have a date column I read in from Excel into R which is formatted with the following date formats: "6/12/2019  12:00:00 AM" and "43716", for example.

I would like to convert this column to the number format MM/DD/YYYY. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58880848 (just adapting the date/time format from that answer's date-only).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to handle both the formats separately

```
#Convert date-time variables into date
df$updated_date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$date_col, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", 
                           tz = "UTC"))
#Get indices of the one which are not converted from above
inds <- is.na(df$updated_date)
#Convert the remaining ones to date
df$updated_date[inds] <- as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(df$date_col[inds])),
                                 origin = "1899-12-30")
#Comvert them to format required
df$updated_date <- format(df$updated_date, "%m/%d/%Y")

df
#  x              date_col updated_date
#1 1 6/12/2019 12:00:00 AM   06/12/2019
#2 2                 43716   09/08/2019
#3 3  6/16/2019 1:00:00 PM   06/16/2019
```

**data**

Tested on this sample data :

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, date_col = c("6/12/2019 12:00:00 AM", "43716", 
                                       "6/16/2019 1:00:00 PM"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend

```
read.csv(file.csv,colClasses="character") #or whatever read function you're using
```

This will make sure that the string is converted properly from the original file into R.

Then I would use `mdy()` from the lubridate package, and the string of characters will be read in as a date object.

Comment: I would strongly advice against this. This will turn *all* columns to `character` vectors, which will require you to manually convert any columns containing numbers back to `numeric` or `integer`.